# paypal pdt first name

Tags: paypal, paypal-pdt

I have a PayPal PDT script and it works with the basic info but I can't get the first and last name from PayPal PDT and stored in a database

Is it possible to get the first name, last name and payer email from PayPal PDT?

If so can anyone provide a code sample

Thank you in advance

Ian

Answer (score 0):

A Typical PDT response would include the following parameters along with `first_name` and `last_name`.

```
SUCCESS
mc_gross=20.00
protection_eligibility=Eligible
address_status=unconfirmed
payer_id=7SGRP23PR8MWY
tax=0.00
address_street=3585+Petunia+Way%0D%0Aaddress+222
payment_date=22%3A13%3A13+Jan+03%2C+2016+PST
payment_status=Completed
charset=UTF-8
address_zip=35045
first_name=dasdsa
mc_fee=1.08
address_country_code=US
address_name=XXX+xxxxx
custom=
payer_status=unverified
business=XXX-facilitator%XXX.com
address_country=United+States
address_city=Clanton
quantity=1
payer_email=XXXYYY%40gmail.com
contact_phone=%2B44+1235415478
txn_id=30F91513AJ293961H
payment_type=instant
payer_business_name=testUK
last_name=dsasa
address_state=AL
receiver_email=XXX-XXX%40gmail.com
payment_fee=1.08
shipping_discount=0.00
insurance_amount=0.00
receiver_id=S4X5XW328WAYY
txn_type=web_accept
item_name=testpdt
discount=0.00
mc_currency=USD
item_number=12112
residence_country=GB
shipping_method=Express
handling_amount=0.00
transaction_subject=
payment_gross=20.00
shipping=10.00
```

[Code Sample](https://github.com/paypal/pdt-code-samples)

[Documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNandPDTVariables/#id092BE0U605Z)